# "Type assign" related errors after possible version changes Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, tslint

I'm working on a legacy project which does not have a package.lock.json or similar file, so npm install does not use versions which the project was successfully built in the past. I'm getting these two kind of errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/angular2-flash-message/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts:24:5 
    TS2416: Property 'lift' in type 'Subject<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Observable<T>'.
  Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
    Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

ERROR in [at-loader] src/app/api/api.service.ts:46:9 
    TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | UserEnvironment>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserEnvironment>'.
  Type '{} | UserEnvironment' is not assignable to type 'UserEnvironment'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'UserEnvironment'.
      Property 'user' is missing in type '{}'.
```

List of installed dependencies (npm ls --depth=0):

```
├── @angular/animations@4.4.6
├── @angular/common@4.4.6
├── @angular/compiler@4.4.6
├── @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 invalid
├── @angular/core@4.4.6
├── @angular/forms@4.4.6
├── @angular/http@4.4.6
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.4.6
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.6
├── @angular/platform-server@4.4.6
├── @angular/router@4.4.6
├── @types/node@7.0.55
├── @types/source-map@0.5.7
├── @types/uglify-js@2.6.30
├── @types/webpack@2.2.16
├── add-asset-html-webpack-plugin@1.0.2
├── angular-2-dropdown-multiselect@1.6.3
├── angular-2-local-storage@1.0.1
├── angular2-flash-message@1.0.2
├── angular2-jwt@0.2.3
├── angular2-moment@1.8.0
├── angular2-template-loader@0.6.2
├── angular2-tinymce@2.1.2
├── assets-webpack-plugin@3.5.1
├── awesome-typescript-loader@3.0.8
├── bootstrap-sass@3.3.7
├── copy-webpack-plugin@4.4.2
├── core-js@2.5.3
├── css-loader@0.26.4
├── exports-loader@0.6.4
├── expose-loader@0.7.4
├── extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0
├── file-loader@0.10.1
├── find-root@1.1.0
├── html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1
├── imports-loader@0.7.1
├── json-loader@0.5.7
├── moment@2.20.1
├── ng-router-loader@2.1.0
├── ngc-webpack@1.1.0
├── ngx-bootstrap@1.9.3
├── node-pre-gyp@0.6.39 extraneous
├── node-sass@4.7.2
├── npm-run-all@4.1.2
├── optimize-js-plugin@0.0.4
├── raw-loader@0.5.1
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.12
├── rimraf@2.6.2
├── rxjs@5.5.6
├── sass-loader@6.0.6
├── script-ext-html-webpack-plugin@1.8.8
├── socket.io-client@1.7.4
├── source-map-loader@0.1.6
├── string-replace-loader@1.0.5
├── style-loader@0.16.1
├── to-string-loader@1.1.5
├── ts-node@2.1.2
├── tslib@1.9.0
├── tslint@4.5.1
├── tslint-loader@3.5.3
├── typescript@2.7.2
├── url-loader@0.5.9
├── webpack@2.3.1
├── webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2
├── webpack-dev-server@2.4.1
├── webpack-dll-bundles-plugin@1.0.0-beta.5
├── webpack-merge@3.0.0
└── zone.js@0.8.20

npm ERR! extraneous: node-pre-gyp@0.6.39 /node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! invalid: @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 /node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12, required by @angular/core@2.2.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12, required by @angular/http@2.2.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12, required by @angular/router@3.2.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: zone.js@^0.6.21, required by @angular/core@2.2.4
```

What dependency should I try to downgrade?

Comment: The second of those appears to be an error in your code. The first is referred to elsewhere on the internet, e.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2705, and looks like an issue with your dependency pulling in incompatible versions.

Comment: downgrading to typescript 2.4.0 made the first type of errors go away, thank you!

Comment: downgrading to typescript 2.3.0 actually made every error to go away, thank you!